# jquery solution like playgif.com

Tags: jquery

since playgif.com is down, see [this](http://techie-buzz.com/internet-tools/pause-rewind-slow-gif-images.html) how it was before.

My guess is they were splitting gifs into sequence of frames and then displaying those via jquery.

Is there any similar solution in jquery that plays sequence of images with controls like speed, loop,stop, pause just like video player ?

I know there are sliders, cycle plugins, but is there anything closer to playgif.com ?
with controls.

[image]

Comment: jQuery can't split GIF to its frames as far as I can tell, for this you need server side language of some sort. Then just use one of the existing plugins you mentioned.

Comment: yes, i know gifs have to be converted server side, i am asking is there anything made in js similar to above

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin: [click](https://github.com/private-face/gif-player) . it has some basic functionality you can work on

Comment: I know this one. not for me

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

[**jsmovie**](https://code.google.com/p/jsmovie/)  has everything i need. recommended **